# How to run application without activity in android version 4.X

Tags: android

Actually my application is running a service only when boot completed. it runs fine in android 2.2.

But when i install 4.0 android supported device it does not work. even after installation application is not running. I know after 3.X android have a change that application is not running when installed.

So how only service oriented application run in > 3.x android version ?

any help is appreciable.

Comment: Why not just create an entry Activity that does bare minimum and closes to meet the requirement?

Answer (score 2):

> How to run application without activity in android version 4.X

You don't.

First, you pretty much always need an activity:

- You need to have your copyright notice somewhere
- You need to have your license agreement somewhere
- You need to have your disclosures of other open source components that you are using somewhere
- You need to provide access to technical support, even if it is just a link to your Web site, somewhere
- You need to allow the user to configure the behavior of the service somewhere
- You need to give the user access to online help somewhere
- You want to avoid the one-star ratings that come from apps that do not have a launcher activity, when the user installs the app, then cannot figure out how to run the app, and thinks that you are a complete moron as a result

This is above and beyond the technical requirement for a component of your app to be manually started before any manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver`s will work.